# ASP.NET Request Validation Ignores URL Encoding

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am running ASP.NET 4 on Azure. I have stumbled into this awesome new feature from Microsoft where the server completely ignores URL Encoding.

At first I had a problem with %26 and was getting error that the & sign is not allowed.
This is clearly a bug because %26 in not & and the whole point of having %26 is to be able safely pass it in urls.

www.example.com/this-is-me-%26-microsoft/

I was able to resolve this by adding this to web config:

```
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="20" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
    <pages validateRequest="false"/>
```

This fixed the %26 issue, but now I see that the problems are far from over because %23 which is encoded #, behaves as if it was # and not %23

www.example.com/%23this-should-work/

I need to resolve this permanently. I don't need this completely wrong request validation.
I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that talks about this insanity, but I can't understand how to utilize this URL_ESCAPE_SEGMENT_ONLY in the web app.

**EDIT:**

Found this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/413312/wcf-uritemplate-strips-some-urlencoded-characters-from-bound-path-segment) from 2009: Looks like this issue is going on for a while now, but noting is being done because Microsoft doesn't care...

**EDIT2!!!:**

After whole day of working on this and trying every possible solution/workaround found on the internet(enough to write a whole book), I have isolated this to be a very specific bug.
My luck was that by pure chance the test case url has the %23 at the beginning of the segment like this.

```
http://www.example.com/%23eleven/
```

Turns out that if the %23 is located at the beginning of the segment it automatically gets unescaped and handled as # and there is no way in the world to change this.

To illustrate this just run this:

```
Response.Write(Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SerializationInfoString, UriFormat.UriEscaped));
```

in a page with a flowing URL

```
http://www.example.com/%23elevenand%23noteleven/
```

The response write will output:

`http://www.example.com/#elevenand%23noteleven/`

Also if you do:

```
Response.Write(Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Fragment, UriFormat.Unescaped));
```

The result will be:

`elevenand#noteleven/`

*P.S. This particular bug aside, what I have learned during the whole day of debugging this, is that the whole URL encoding and decoding in .NET is a complete disaster both in all the legacy(pre .NET 4), but also all the new .NET 4 modifications are even greater disaster like adding a gas to a fire. None of it works as it should, there are tons of posts on the boards by users reporting this, but Microsoft ignores everything and closes the reported bugs as resolved and duplicate.*

Comment: %26 (as hex 26) is &, and %23 is #